# php woocommerce ID Custom Field displaying in URL

Tags: php

Pasted Custom Field code into Woo commerce template to display a Custom Field Link.

Code used is:

```
<a href="<?php the_field('datasheet',the_ID()); ?>" >Download File</a>
```

But in the front end it adds the Product ID into the url.

it ends up looking like this:

```
<a href="462https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/2c1ff8dc9046ed92d5e254770412c898.pdf">Download Datasheet</a>
```

Any ideas?

```
<a href="<?php the_field('datasheet',the_ID()); ?>" >Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <a href="<?php the_field('datasheet',the_ID()); ?>" >Download File</a>
> ```

The purpose of `the_ID()` is to *display* the post id, meaning it will *echo* it.

You want `get_the_ID()` here, which only *returns* the id, but does not directly output it.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I missed!